# Stream RTSP stream from IP camera via Kurento Media Server over WebRTC

Tags: webrtc, rtsp, kurento

I have to create a WebRTC solution where I have multiple IP camera in a private network and have to stream the feeds to a mobile application outside the network. I am using Kurento Media Server to help me generate a WebRTC stream from the RTSP stream from the camera. I have installed KMS(Kurento Media Server) in the private network as well.

I followed a similar setup to https://github.com/lulop-k/kurento-rtsp2webrtc except for the fact that I created a pipeline with a PlayerEndpoint with the camera stream URI and a WebRTCEndpoint connected to it as shown below.

```
function playCam(message){
  console.log("Message:" + JSON.stringify(message));
  var cam_url = message.cam_url;
  var sdpOffer = message.sdpOffer;
  getKurentoClient(function(error, kurentoClient) {

  console.log("Kurento client created.");
  kurentoClient.create('MediaPipeline', function(error, pipeline) {
  if (error) {
    console.log("Error: Creating Media Pipeline failed.");
    stop(pipeline);
    return;
  }

  console.log("Pipeline created.");
  pipeline.create("PlayerEndpoint", {uri: cam_url}, function(error, player){
      if(error) {
          console.log("Error: Creating PlayerEndpoint failed.");
          stop(pipeline);
          return;
        }

        console.log("PlayerEndpoint created.");
        pipeline.create("WebRtcEndpoint", function(error, webRtcEndpoint){

        remoteWebRtcEndpoint = webRtcEndpoint;
            console.log("WebRtcEndpoint created.");
            webRtcEndpoint.processOffer(sdpOffer, function(error, sdpAnswer){

                      sendSdpAnswer(sdpAnswer);

          for(var i = 0; i < remoteCandidates.length; i++){
            addIceRemoteCandidate(remoteCandidates[i]);
          }

                      webRtcEndpoint.gatherCandidates(function(error) {
                          console.log("Gathering Ice candidates created.");
                    });
                });

                player.connect(webRtcEndpoint, function(error){
                    console.log("PlayerEndpoint-->WebRtcEndpoint connection established");

                    player.play(function(error){
                        console.log("Player playing ...");
                    });
                });

        webRtcEndpoint.on('OnIceCandidate', function(event) {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(event));
            var candidate = kurento.getComplexType('IceCandidate')(event.candidate);
            sendIceCandidate(candidate);
          });
        });
      });
    });
  });
}
```

I used a web socket in the cloud to signal sdpOffer, sdpAnswer, iceCandidate messages.

At the client side I have the javascript implementation that uses a WebRTC Peer as shown below.

```
var ws = new WebSocket(ws.url);
var webRtcPeer;
ws.onmessage = function(message) {
  var parsedMessage = JSON.parse(message.data);

  switch (parsedMessage.id) {
    case 'iceCandidate':
      webRtcPeer.addIceCandidate(parsedMessage.candidate)
      break;
    case 'sdpAnswer':
      webRtcPeer.processAnswer(parsedMessage.sdpAnswer);
      break;
    default:
      onError('Unrecognized message', parsedMessage);
  }
}

window.addEventListener('load', function(){
  var videoOutput = document.getElementById('videoOutput');
  var address = camera_rtsp_stream_url;
  var pipeline;

  function start() {
    var options = {
      remoteVideo : videoOutput,
      configuration: {
        iceServers:[
         { "url": turn_url,
           "username": uname,
           "credential": pass
         }
       ]
      }
    };

    webRtcPeer = kurentoUtils.WebRtcPeer.WebRtcPeerRecvonly(options,
      function(error){
      webRtcPeer.generateOffer(onOffer);
      setIceCandidateCallbacks();
    });
  }

  function onOffer(error, sdpOffer){
    var message = {
      id : 'sdpOffer',
      name: 'peer',
      cam_url: address,
      sdpOffer : sdpOffer
    };
    sendMessage(message);
  }

});

function sendMessage(message) {
  var jsonMessage = JSON.stringify(message);
  ws.send(jsonMessage);
}

function setIceCandidateCallbacks(){
  webRtcPeer.on('icecandidate', function(candidate){
    candidate = kurentoClient.register.complexTypes.IceCandidate(candidate);

    var message = {
      id : 'iceCandidate',
      name: 'peer',
      iceCandidate : candidate
    };
    sendMessage(message);

  });

}
```

Still the feed is not working in page. However, the example in the git repo works perfect. Is there something I am missing.

Thanks in advance.

Edit:

This is my SDP Offer.

```
v=0
o=- 62767501284085133 2 IN IP4 127.0.0.1
s=-
t=0 0
a=group:BUNDLE audio video
a=msid-semantic: WMS
m=audio 9 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 111 103 104 9 0 8 106 105 13 126
c=IN IP4 0.0.0.0
a=rtcp:9 IN IP4 0.0.0.0
a=ice-ufrag:AoAe
a=ice-pwd:tp+DQSO/OTvBaDZYQOmb5Yxe
a=fingerprint:sha-256     14:03:6A:CB:9D:86:B5:57:09:30:97:D8:0A:0E:59:A2:0F:8D:5F:24:46:3E:14:C7:D3:23:B2:11:39:4C:61:33
a=setup:actpass
a=mid:audio
a=extmap:1 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:ssrc-audio-level
a=extmap:3 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/abs-send-time
a=recvonly
a=rtcp-mux
a=rtpmap:111 opus/48000/2
a=rtcp-fb:111 transport-cc
a=fmtp:111 minptime=10;useinbandfec=1
a=rtpmap:103 ISAC/16000
a=rtpmap:104 ISAC/32000
a=rtpmap:9 G722/8000
a=rtpmap:0 PCMU/8000
a=rtpmap:8 PCMA/8000
a=rtpmap:106 CN/32000
a=rtpmap:105 CN/16000
a=rtpmap:13 CN/8000
a=rtpmap:126 telephone-event/8000
m=video 9 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 100 101 107 116 117 96 97 99 98
c=IN IP4 0.0.0.0
a=rtcp:9 IN IP4 0.0.0.0
a=ice-ufrag:AoAe
a=ice-pwd:tp+DQSO/OTvBaDZYQOmb5Yxe
a=fingerprint:sha-256 14:03:6A:CB:9D:86:B5:57:09:30:97:D8:0A:0E:59:A2:0F:8D:5F:24:46:3E:14:C7:D3:23:B2:11:39:4C:61:33
a=setup:actpass
a=mid:video
a=extmap:2 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:toffset
a=extmap:3 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/abs-send-time
a=extmap:4 urn:3gpp:video-orientation
a=extmap:6 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/playout-delay
a=recvonly
a=rtcp-mux
a=rtcp-rsize
a=rtpmap:100 VP8/90000
a=rtcp-fb:100 ccm fir
a=rtcp-fb:100 nack
a=rtcp-fb:100 nack pli
a=rtcp-fb:100 goog-remb
a=rtcp-fb:100 transport-cc
a=rtpmap:101 VP9/90000
a=rtcp-fb:101 ccm fir
a=rtcp-fb:101 nack
a=rtcp-fb:101 nack pli
a=rtcp-fb:101 goog-remb
a=rtcp-fb:101 transport-cc
a=rtpmap:107 H264/90000
a=rtcp-fb:107 ccm fir
a=rtcp-fb:107 nack
a=rtcp-fb:107 nack pli
a=rtcp-fb:107 goog-remb
a=rtcp-fb:107 transport-cc
a=fmtp:107 level-asymmetry-allowed=1;packetization-mode=1;profile-level-id=42e01f
a=rtpmap:116 red/90000
a=rtpmap:117 ulpfec/90000
a=rtpmap:96 rtx/90000
a=fmtp:96 apt=100
a=rtpmap:97 rtx/90000
a=fmtp:97 apt=101
a=rtpmap:99 rtx/90000
a=fmtp:99 apt=107
a=rtpmap:98 rtx/90000
a=fmtp:98 apt=116
```

SDP Answer is as shown below:

```
v=0
o=- 3687061549 3687061549 IN IP4 0.0.0.0
s=Kurento Media Server
c=IN IP4 0.0.0.0
t=0 0
a=msid-semantic: WMS
a=group:BUNDLE audio video
m=audio 1 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 111 0
a=extmap:3 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/abs-send-time
a=mid:audio
a=rtcp:9 IN IP4 0.0.0.0
a=rtpmap:111 opus/48000/2
a=rtpmap:0 PCMU/8000
a=setup:active
a=sendonly
a=rtcp-mux
a=fmtp:111 minptime=10;useinbandfec=1
a=ssrc:174718429 cname:user1410268339@host-e518075a
a=ice-ufrag:Y1e8
a=ice-pwd:rLobIsorf9OWA8VkEvGbJN
a=fingerprint:sha-256 EF:8B:94:E4:CF:2A:82:BD:2D:07:F6:35:B8:2A:4C:4A:7F:A5:8D:FE:06:5F:38:6C:E7:F8:10:07:3C:11:E1:28
m=video 1 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 100
a=extmap:3 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/abs-send-time
a=mid:video
a=rtcp:9 IN IP4 0.0.0.0
a=rtpmap:100 VP8/90000
a=rtcp-fb:100 ccm fir
a=rtcp-fb:100 nack
a=rtcp-fb:100 nack pli
a=rtcp-fb:100 goog-remb
a=setup:active
a=sendonly
a=rtcp-mux
a=ssrc:3344771 cname:user1410268339@host-e518075a
a=ice-ufrag:Y1e8
a=ice-pwd:rLobIsorf9OWA8VkEvGbJN
a=fingerprint:sha-256 EF:8B:94:E4:CF:2A:82:BD:2D:07:F6:35:B8:2A:4C:4A:7F:A5:8D:FE:06:5F:38:6C:E7:F8:10:07:3C:11:E1:28
```

Comment: Any errors that you see in the logs that might help people help you? You need to check for logs in the server and in the client. Maybe the player can't access the RTSP feed. The best thing you can do is search for differences in your code and the original code.

Comment: Thanks, @igracia . I have one query though. I am generating an sdp offer at the WebRTCPeer. However, I am not generating an sdp offer at the WebRTCendpoint connected to the PlayerEndPoint. I am just processing the sdp offer from the WebRTCPeer at the WebRTCEndpoint, and sending over the sdp answer back to the WebRTCPeer. Should I be creating an sdp offer at the WebRTCEndpoint too and send it across?

Comment: @igracia, I am able to get the stream to render when the WebRTCPeer is in the local network. However, when I switch to a different network behind a NAT, it does play. The iceConnectionState stated goes to failed state. The SDP offer/answer and ICE candidates are getting exchanged alright. I dont find the candidate information in the SDP Offer/Answer. Is it required? Am I doing it wrong?

Comment: You most likely need to add a STUN server to your KMS configuration. Check [this](https://doc-kurento.readthedocs.io/en/stable/installation_guide.html#stun-and-turn-servers) for more info on how to do that.

Comment: Thanks, @igracia. The addition of the STUN server worked. The RTSP stream is working now. I just had the turnUrl set earlier. But that brings me to another question.  Network NAT within which I had the WebRTCPeer, the ICE connection happened. STUN worked in that case. How can I get it to work across a NAT that can only work with TURN traversal? ICE connection is still failing when I have to switch to TURN relay. I need to check if its something I am doing wrong at the TURN server.

Comment: -n --no-tls --nodtls provided in the turnserver command got the stream up and running. Surprising!

Comment: @georgekuruvillak do you have the rest of your project on a repo or something ? I am trying to do something similar. Thank you.

Comment: @LukeKroon There are three projects in my github repo.
[Client](https://github.com/georgekuruvillak/webrtc-camera-rtsp), [Server](https://github.com/georgekuruvillak/kurento-camera-cloud), [Signalling server](https://github.com/georgekuruvillak/signaling-ws)

Its quite rudimentary but works.